# Microsoft SSIS Conditional Split is not working correctly

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I need to do the conditional split of data based on the source file record count and process data count if both count match then only i need to perform the insert into DB table but some where my conditional split is failing please find the screen shot and let me know what is wrong

[image]
[image]

Comment: two variables @[User::v_OriginalRowCount]  store the count of source file  and @[User::v_extractRowCount]  store the count of process data and conditional split condition is @[User::v_OriginalRowCount] == @[User::v_extractRowCount]

Comment: how you get @[User::v_OrigianlRowCount]? this one only can get at last row been processed, and for @[User::v_extractRowCount], count of process data means row already been processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't think that you can achieve that within one data flow task**, since variables values are committed at the end of Data flow Task execution.

In your case it will always shows that the row counts are equals since they are both equals to zero.

You have to create 2 data flow task and one script task:

1. First Data Flow Task to get the Original Count and Extracted count and to store them within two variables.
2. Second Data Flow Task is to import Data into an OLE DB Destination (just a Flat File Source and an OLE DB Destination)
3. The Script Task is to notify user that the data is Invalid

Add a precedence constraint between the First DFT and the second one. In addition, add a precedence constraint between the first DFT and the Script Task

On each precedence constraint add an expression:

*Between Data Flow Tasks*

```
@[User:OriginalRowCount] == @[User::ExtractedRowCount]
```

*Between DFT and Script Task*

```
@[User:OriginalRowCount] != @[User::ExtractedRowCount]
```

Comment: Can you suggest me by referring the attached images

Comment: As the same way you used to send a success or failure email, add a Data Flow Task if row counts are equals, on the other side add a script task or another task to notify user that row counts are not equals

Answer (score 0):

Put an expression on the precedence constraint between conditional split and OutputRowCount and put the same expression in there. Simple fix.

Comment: How i can provide precedence constraint in Data Flow

Comment: here is my Control flow